# Как сделать запрос по трём связанным таблицам, чтобы посчитать количество нужных записей?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

В SQL Server есть три таблички - "Список детей", "Образовательные учреждения" и "Населённые пункты".

Основная цель: Посчитать сколько детей проживает в каждом населённом пункте.
То есть чтобы можно было вывести запись по типу "г. Красноярск - 500 детей" (это к примеру).
Чтобы посчитать количество детей в определённом населённом пункте, я хочу посчитать сколько детей учится в образовательных учреждениях этого населённого пункта, а потом просто сложить эти числа (надеюсь, понятно написал). И так сделать по каждому населённому пункту.

Для большего понимания, думаю, стоит написать какие столбцы есть в таблицах.

**Список детей** - "*id ребёнка*", "*ФИО*", "*id Образовательного учреждения*".

**Образовательные учреждения** - "*id учреждения*", "*Наименование*", "*id населённого пункта*".

**Населённые пункты** - "*id населённого пункта*", "*Наименование насел. пункта*".

Уже несколько дней мучаюсь, не могу додуматься. Я написал код, который просто выводит id населённого пункта и сколько в нём детей. Но как сложить нужных детей только из нужных населённых пунктов - не понимаю

```
//База подключена через ADO.NET (NET Framework)
//КодОрганизациии - это id образовательного учреждения
var children = ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext().СписокДетей.GroupBy(x => x.КодОрганизации).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach (var obrUch in children)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"{obrUch.Name} : {obrUch.Count}");
}
```

(В идеале, конечно, там есть ещё четвёртая таблица типа "Регионы". И можно было бы сразу ещё посчитать сколько детей в регионе. Но пока что мне и этого хватит. Просто если есть какие-то идеи, буду рад почитать)

Можно хотя бы сам SQL запрос как-то сформировать, а дальше попробую сам написать этот запрос на C#.

Comment: Ещё раз: что такое `ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext()`? Это какая-то ORM? Какая именно? Или это ваш репозиторий?

Comment: @Alexander я работаю на wpf. Подключил базу через ADO.NET и в модели базы, в файле BaseModel.Context.cs вот такой код

    `public partial class ВедущийСпециалистEntities : DbContext

{
     ....

        private static ВедущийСпециалистEntities _context;

        public static ВедущийСпециалистEntities GetContext()
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new ВедущийСпециалистEntities();
            }

            return _context;
        }}`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я просто не силён особо в определениях (делал по гайдам). Я почитал, думаю, да, это ORM.
Но на всякий случай, могу добавить что такое ADO.NET
Эта технология представляет набор классов, через которые мы можем отправлять запросы к базам данных, устанавливать подключения, получать ответ от базы данных и производить ряд других операций.

Comment: Хорошо, понятно. Судя по `DbContext` - это Entity Framework. А так как используется .NET Framework, становится ясно, что это EF 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это sql server то это обыкновенный sql запрос

как я понял

```
у школы есть поле регион,
у ребенка есть поле школа
```

поэтому запрос примерно такой:
привязываем ребенка к школе и считаем их количество с групировкой по полю регион.

```
select count(c.children_id) 
from Childrens c
inner join Schools s on c.School_id = s.School_id
group by s.Region_id
```